# Can't remove root

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, backup

I have rooted in my Asus Zenfone 2 Laser 1 month ago but now I want to delete it. I tried to delete it by following some guides without success. Could someone help me, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Asus has this problem, try to follow this guide made to mail for Asus that permit you to remove root.
http://www.android.gs/root-asus-zenfone-2/